# CSS flexbox navigation menu - overlaps when not enough height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a navigation menu with a fixed height header like this...

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.navigation_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation_header {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

#mobileNavMenuContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

#navigationList {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="navigation_container">
    <div class="navigation_header">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div id="mobileNavMenuContainer">
      <ul id="navigationList">
        <li>Menu Item 1</li>
        <li>Menu Item 2</li>
        <li>Menu Item 3</li>
        <li>Menu Item 4</li>
        <li>Menu Item 5</li>
        <li>Menu Item 6</li>
        <li>Menu Item 7</li>
        <li>Menu Item 8</li>
        <li>Menu Item 9</li>
        <li>Menu Item 10</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

When there is enough space, the menu list should be centered in the reamining space underneath the fixed height header.

When there is not enough space, the whole thing should scroll, but currently the menu overlaps the header when the screen height is decreased.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are setting height: 100% for <div class="navigation"> which is may lead you this kind of issue, when you are using height:100% make sure you should have height for for parent element..

Comment: But .navigation is the parent element is it not?

Comment: is possible to attached the page design in the question. so that Myself/others can help you in best way..

Comment: The page design is already in the question

Comment: Fine. try to set height value in px/pt instead of % and if your want to set height  in % then you have to set min-height / height ( px/pt) for body tag,. try with this one and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I think its `pointer-events: none;` , that's the reason its not scrolling.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 70%;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navigation_container {
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation_header {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

#mobileNavMenuContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

#navigationList {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">

  <div class="navigation_container">

    <div class="navigation_header">
      Logo
    </div>

    <div id="mobileNavMenuContainer">

      <ul id="navigationList">
        <li>Menu Item 1</li>
        <li>Menu Item 2</li>
        <li>Menu Item 3</li>
        <li>Menu Item 4</li>
        <li>Menu Item 5</li>
        <li>Menu Item 6</li>
        <li>Menu Item 7</li>
        <li>Menu Item 8</li>
        <li>Menu Item 9</li>
        <li>Menu Item 10</li>
        <li>Menu Item 11</li>
        <li>Menu Item 12</li>
        <li>Menu Item 13</li>
        <li>Menu Item 14</li>
        <li>Menu Item 15</li>
        <li>Menu Item 16</li>
        <li>Menu Item 17</li>
        <li>Menu Item 18</li>
        <li>Menu Item 19</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: But in your example the header is not 100px as set out in the CSS

Comment: yes, Just because you are using flex. Still can't understand why you are using too much flex which is not needed in this simple structure.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I removed flex from `navigation_container`

Comment: That is worse, same issue with the header not keeping the height as well as a new issue with the list not being vertically centered

Comment: Please post a picture of what you really want to achieve  so I can fully understand it.